# Ordering of field beyond parent and child models in inlineformset_factory blank form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a setup below:

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS, default="To be confirmed")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

**views.py**

```
def createOrder(request, pk):
    OrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Order, fields=('product', 'status'), extra=5)
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    formset = OrderFormSet(queryset=Order.objects.none().order_by("product__name"), instance=customer)
```

The form shown up is a blank form as expected but the field "product" shown cannot be ordered by 'name'.  How can the drop down list in "product" field can be sorted by '**name**' as currently only sorted by 'id'. Any help is highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not set `ordering = ['name']` in the `Meta` of the `Product`?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the meta in model.py and it works now!